# Detect Apple MusicKit ApplicationMusicPlayer player's playback state changes

Tags: ios, swift, apple-musickit

Integrated `MusicKit` in iOS swift application and I want to know is there a way to detect `ApplicationMusicPlayer` player's playback state changes?